# How to pass input value while executing a jar file using groovy

Tags: groovy, jar, soapui

I have a jar file which has multiple switch cases.

I'm executing the jar by using the below line

```
def p = "java -jar xxx.jar".execute().text
```

But i couldnt get the input line to give my input to choose the switch case. But in cmd prompt i am able to do that manually. But here im trying to do it here in soap UI tool.

Answer (score 0):

as i understand, you want to write something to STDIN stream of your jar application

you can do like this:

```
def p=["java", "-jar", "xxx.jar"].execute()
def error=new StringWriter()
def output=new StringWriter()
//write some strings to STDIN of your app 
p.withWriter{ it.append("hello").append('\n').append('world!') }
//wait for process end
p.waitForProcessOutput(output, error)

println "output=$output"
println "error=$error"
```